# Trim ref text posted in Excel VBA editor

Tags: vba, excel

`enter code here`I have my following code a bit short in the process of working on it, so I am trying to get text from a .txt file to be displayed in a cell on Excel, the code will be

```
Sub citi()
Dim c As Range
Open "C:\Users\alvaradod\Desktop\citi macro\Import File.txt" For Input As #1
R = 0
Dim i As Range
Dim num As Integer
Dim arrData() As String
the_value = Sheets("Prog").Range("A1")
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, Data
If Not Left(Data, 1) = "" Then
'import this row
R = R + 1
Cells(R, 1).Value = Data
'Mid(the_value, 3, 5)
'Left(Data, Len(Data) - 3)).Value
End If
Loop
For Each i In Range("A1")
i.Select
ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").Mid(Data(i), 49, 5).Select
'ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Import").Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(num, 0).PasteSpecial
ActiveCell.Rows.Delete
 num = num + 1
Next i
```

End Sub

" LINE 11 WILL PAST THE TEXT FROM LINE ONE ON .TXT FILE TO EXCEL, AFTER THIS FUNCTION I NEED TO TRIM THIS SAME TEXT IN THE EXCEL SHEET TO SHOW THE FIRST 5 CHARACTERS"

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but perhaps something like this?

```
Sub citi()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim arrData() As String
    Dim arrImport1(1 To 65000) As String
    Dim arrImport2(1 To 65000) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    arrData = Split(oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Test\test.txt").ReadAll, vbCrLf)

    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i)) > 0 Then
            j = j + 1
            arrImport1(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 3, 5)
            arrImport2(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 49, 5)
        End If
    Next i

    If j > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(arrImport1)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(arrImport2)
    End If

    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Erase arrData
    Erase arrImport

End Sub
```

Comment: How about if I was to to have 5 rows of information on a sheet, about 30 characters long each row, and I want to get the characters from location 34 through 40, what would be the way or function to go about this? and thanks that code did work.

Comment: If each row is about 30 characters long, and you wanted characters from location 34 through 40, wouldn't that just return blanks because there aren't any characters at those locations?  Anyway, you would just change the Mid function `Mid(arrData(i), 34, 7)`

Comment: How about for the following code I am resplacing the EntireRow.Select "Line 22" for "ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").Mid(Data(i), 49, 5).Select"

Comment: I can see you created a duplicate post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211855/copy-and-past-text-using-mid-function-vba-excel).

Can you describe what you want to do, step-by-step, in plain English?

Comment: I have 2 worksheets (worksheet1, worksheet2), the macro (code) will go to the text file (line#3) and pull the data to worksheet1 (line#10), the next step in the code will be to copy each line to worksheet2 using the mid() function to subtrack a specific amount of characters from each line. (line#21) however I do not believe that line21 is correct and would like to get your opinion on this.

Comment: See edited answer, you'll need to change the sheet names to their actual names