# Excel VBA script modify text trimming first 4 characters

Tags: vba, excel, trim

I would like to write VBA script to trim the first characters in each row.

I know i can format cells with Cells Format > custom

But if i want to compare the content of the cells later, the trimmed characters are nevertheless taken into account in the comparison.

I am new to VBA, how can i quickly trim text for text comparison ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18193731/62576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Select** the cells you want to trim and run this tiny macro:

```
Sub trimmit()
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        r.Value = Mid(v, 5)
    Next r
End Sub
```

I am assuming that if a cell contains **ABCDE**, it will become **E**